# Insert pause in column with markdown to revealjs using pandoc

Tags: markdown, pandoc, reveal.js

I would like to add a pause to the content in a column in a markdown document to be converted into a revealjs presentation using pandoc.

Is this possible?

````
----

<!-- this works just fine -->

# Slide with a pause

content before the pause

. . .

content after the pause

-------

# Slide with a pause in a column

::::::: {.columns}

::: {.column width="50%"}

```python
if __name__ == "__main__":
    print "Hello World"
```

:::

::: {.column width="50%"}

<!-- this does not work -->  
content before the pause

. . .

content after the pause

<!-- this works (with the `-i` flag), but is not ideal -->
* ```python
if __name__ == "__main__":
    print "Hello World"
```


:::

:::::::

--------
````

```sh
pandoc -s -i -t revealjs --section-divs -o slides.html slides.md
```